# How to find which files came from which machine?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, diff

I have a bash shell script which moves the file from `machineB` and `machineC` into `machineA`.

File name is like below and it will be inside this directory - `/data/pe_t1_snapshot/20140320` in `machineB` and `machineC`

```
weekly_1980_991_200003_5.data
```

Above file name is going to be same always only the file number which is `991` is going to be change as I have multiple files.

Is there any way to find out what are the files which came from `machineB` and which files came from `machineC` into `machineA` using some sort of subset of files `(diff in bash)`. I would like to run the command from `machineA` to find out about the files.

Below is one way I can think of. I will be running the below command on machineA where my files are but somehow it doesn't return me those files which came from `machineC`

```
diff -B <(ssh user@machineC "ls -R ~/20140320/") <(ls -R .)
```

Is there anything wrong I am doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like :

```
cat <(ssh user@machineC "ls 20140320|sort -u") <(ls .|sort -u)|sort|uniq -d # list of file provided by machineC
cat <(ssh user@machineB "ls 20140320|sort -u") <(ls .|sort -u)|sort|uniq -d # list of file provided by machineB
```

Comment: Thanks Idriss for the help. Do I need to provide full path of the directory where the files are instead of providing `20140320`? And also it will output the result on the console?

Comment: @SSH You can but that's not required if the directory is located in the home directory of the user (/home/<user_name> or /root for root).